# What's the best way to avoid SQL injection in Perl when passing values to Sybase queries?

Tags: sql, perl, sql-injection, sybase

What's the best way to avoid SQL injection in Perl when passing values to Sybase queries?

I'm worried about the "Bobby tables" SQL injection problem in my Perl code connecting to Sybase.

Obviously, doing something like this:

```
 my $var = $ARGV[3]; # Example! I use Getopt for real
 my $sql = "select * from table1 where key1='$var'";
 $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
 $sth->execute();
```

... is very bad, since user may pass code like `1'\ngo\ndrop table important_table\ngo'` as a parameter value on command line.

I know of 2 solutions, both bad:

- Strip all the single quotes off using `s/'//g;`

  This is not good for real life, because sometimes users may legitimately want to pass strings containing apostrophes (last names, for instance).
- Write a complicated regex detecting possible SQL injections

  This seems nearly impossible to get right from my several attempts.

What's the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 approaches:

- Find a CPAN library that does SQL injection detection for you. I read good things about [`SQL::Abstract`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SQL%3a%3aAbstract).
- Use [`quote_identifier`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#quote_identifier)
- Use **[binding](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#bind_param)** of parameters (not as common in Perl, but typically used when doing DB access in JDBC from Java and such).

  This is very easy:

  ```
  my $var = $ARGV[3]; # Copying your example
  my $sql = "select * from table1 where key1=?";
  my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql); # You forgot 'my' in your code!
  $sth->bind_param( 1, $var ); # 1 is the first instance of "?" in query.
  $sth->execute();
  ```

Now, DBI will **bind** the value of $var into the query where the first "?" is.

A good reading material is Randal Schwartz's article [here](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/UnixReview/col58.html).

Answer (score 4):

The best way to avoid SQL injection is to use `?` placeholders in sql queries for input values,

```
my $sql = 'select * from table1 where key1 = ?';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($var);
```

as a positive side effect you can use prepared statement for repeated `$sth->execute`, which can be useful for mass insertion or row update.